# Nested loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

loop1 start

loop2 start

loop3 start

X

end loop3

end loop 2

end loop 1

Can I store the value of X such that I can see all the values after execution of all the loops? Just mentioning X is text strings.

Update: it's working,. I'm getting an output like:

```
       {790x1 cell}
          []
          []
          []
          []
          []
          []
          []
          []
          []
```

I guess, all my strings are saved in the {790x1 cell}. Is there any way to see them? The code:

```
X_record=cell(10000,1);
c=1;
for k=1:200
    for i=1:300
        for it=1:200
           X='NY is crowded';
           X_record{c}=X;
           c=c+1;
        end
    end
end
```

**EDIT:2**

```
clear all
clc

X_record=cell(10,1);
c=1;

for k=1:2
    for i=1:3
        for it=1:2
           X='NY is crowded';

           f_id=fopen('c.txt','a+');
           fprintf(f_id,'%5s\n',X) ;%#ok<CTPCT,CTPCT>
           fclose(f_id)

           X_record{c}=X;
           c=c+1;
        end
    end
end
```

OUTPUT:

NY is crowded
    NY is crowded NY is crowded NY is crowded NY is crowded NY is crowded.....

**Why am I not getting any new line?**

Comment: Please provide a 'real' example.

Comment: If you post actual code, we can probably show you how to not use loops at all.

Comment: I'll try to upload the code from next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html):

```
X_record = cell(M*N*P,1);

c = 1;
for i = 1:M
    for j = 1:N
        for k = 1:N
            X = whatever;
            X_record{c} = X;
            c = c + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Or `X_record = cell(M,N,P)` and later `X_record{i,j,k} = X`. You can still using 1-d indexing to access them in-order later if desired.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question about why you aren't seeing each `NY is crowded` on a new line, I'm guessing you are probably viewing your file `c.txt` using Microsoft Notepad. Here is an excerpt from the ["Examples"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html#br5acdq-6) section of the documentation for the function [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html):

> MATLAB import functions, all UNIX
>   applications, and Microsoft Word and
>   WordPad recognize `'\n'` as a newline
>   indicator. However, if you plan to
>   read the file with Microsoft Notepad,
>   use `'\r\n'` to move to a new line when
>   writing.

So, you should try printing the output like so:

```
fprintf(f_id,'%5s\r\n',X);
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of reading the function detail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why

```
       X='NY is crowded';
       fprintf(f_id,'%5s\n',X)
```

..does not work, but I suggest you try

```
       X='NY is crowded\n';
       fprintf(f_id,'%5s',X)
```

...instead